# How to save the drawn rectangle in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm very new to OpenCV and I'm working on a Video,  where I have to detect moving objects and draw a rectangle around the object. I have to draw rectangles for each object that is being detected. I drew the rectangle using the code below. Now I want to save the rectangle, can someone please tell me how to save the rectangle as image ?

The code is

```
rectangle( frameSequence, Point( x-20, y+20), Point( x+20, y-20), Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), +1, 4 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get a submatrix or roi. You may want a deep copy

```
cv::Mat frame;
//get the frame ...
cv::Mat subFrame = frame(cv::Rect(x, y, w, h).clone();
or
cv::Mat subFrame;
frame(cv::Rect(x, y, w, h)).copyTo(subFrame);
imwrite(filename, subframe);
```

Answer (score 1):

`frameSequence` is already a type of cv::mat (presumably) that means it is already "saved" in terms of stored within your program.

If you want to "save" this to an external file (.jpg etc) then you will need to use [imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html):

```
imwrite( "../../images/rectangle.jpg",frameSequence);
```

In order to save only the rectangle to a mat you need to simply create a blank matrix and then pass that to `rectangle()`. THis will mean that the only data within this new matrix will be the coordinates of the rectangle.

```
cv::Mat newRectMat;
rectangle( newRectMat, Point( x-20, y+20), Point( x+20, y-20), Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), +1, 4 );
```

Comment: frameSequence is already type of cv::mat . But your code saves the entire frame as image . I want to save  the Rectangle part only .

Comment: as in you want a mat with only the coordinates of the rectangle?

Comment: Yes exactly , I want the rectangle which I drawed with the above piece of code .

Comment: I dint get you . after Some processing i have detected some objects in     . And I'm drawing  rectangle  on it (in mat Framesequence). How can I draw the rectangle in New Blank Mat with out any thing , The Framesequence Mat has rectangle

Comment: Drawing the rectangle is completely independent of your processing. The processing gives you the values for your rectangle. You can then draw it wherever you want

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `rectangle( FrameSequence, Point( x-20, y+20), Point( x+20, y-20), Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), +1, 4 );
   cv::Mat newRectMat;
   rectangle( newRectMat, Point( x-20, y+20), Point( x+20, y-20), Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), +1, 4 );
   char filename[200];
   sprintf(filename,"rectangle_%d.jpg",i);
   imwrite(filename,newRectMat);`               I tried this it just saves empty Image.

Comment: try making the +1 just 1